# PHP access member variable using constant

Tags: php

This is an very simplified example of some code that is probably overcoded, but I want to access a class member variable using a class constant and was wondering if there's a simpler syntax than using the $foo->__get below?

```
class Foo
{
    const BAR = 'bar';

    private $props = array( self::BAR => 'wee' );

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->props[$name];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->__get(Foo::BAR);
```

Comment: @MikeBrant That would return "bar", not "wee", right?

Comment: Sorry I realized I didn't read the question right.  It would absolutely return `bar` but that is what I read the question to originally be looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also works:

```
$foo->{Foo::BAR};
```

Or implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), then you can have:

```
$foo[Foo::BAR]
```

But why not access it as `$foo->bar` ?! Are you planning to change that constant a lot or am I missing something here?

Comment: Foo is an autogenerated class that doesn't change much but it does on occasion. This is just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the code looks good, but you could use the constructor to initialize the `props` array:

```
class Foo
{
    const BAR = 'bar';

    private $props;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->props = array( self::BAR => 'wee' );
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->props[$name];
    }
}
```

Comment: [Why not](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iccdMD)? Constants can be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: But they cannot be used in class (property) declaration constructs. Why not? -> this qould require the PHP parser to handle dependencies proprerly. but the php parser doesn't

Comment: Hey you are right! :) Thanks for taking the time to prepare that example (Note that I really appreciate, if somebody *shows* me that I'm wrong :) )

Comment: My pleasure, I feel the same way as you about learning things. I thought you might have a good point about dependency, that perhaps it wouldn't work if the constant is defined in a different file that hasn't been `include`d yet. But no, all my attempts at that still work without error. :-p

Comment: Btw, I have tested the (question's) example yet. It works for me. What do you say?